# c++ 14 Categorized List of 3 Strings

Tags: c++, list, multidimensional-array, c++14

My brain is fried this morning, and I am struggling to understand why I am getting a compiler error.

`error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'list<data::tweak_cat>'`

My code is this:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

// fire up our std namespace
using namespace std;

namespace data {

    // create a structure to hold the tweak data
    struct the_tweak {
        string _name;
        string _value;
        string _type;
    };

    // create a structure to hold our category data
    struct tweak_cat {
        string _category;
        list< the_tweak > data;
    };

    class properties {
        public:
            // return our lists of strings for the tweak properties
            static list< tweak_cat > tweak_properties( ) {
                // hold the return
                list< tweak_cat > _ret = { 
                    { "debugging", 
                        { "testing", "0", "" }, 
                    },
                    { "dozing", 
                        { "testing2", "this", "" }, 
                        { "testing3", "that", "" }, 
                        { "testing4", "0", "theother" }, 
                    },
                };
                
                // return it
                return _ret;
            }
    };
}
```

I am building a cli based set of tweaks for my phone, in the process attempting to teach myself some c++ and compiling for it.  Where am I going wrong, and how can I correct it?

It is my understanding (from reading) that lists are the more efficient method to "store" this type of data, over vectors and arrays... I initially had these as `vector< vector< string > >` without the category parent, and it worked ok...

Comment: for "dozing" you are providing 3 lists when 1 is expected. You want to do nested list there. Same applies for "debugging" as well actually.

Comment: A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: _"lists are the more efficient method to "store" this type of data, over vectors and arrays"_ - why do you think that ?

Comment: (1) You are missing `{` and `}` around the `tweak_cat::data` level of list initializers. That’s the most obvious error. (2) Use C++20 and [designated intializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers); it will make the error obvious, the initialization less error-prone etc. (3) Please remove `using namespace std;`; it is an antipattern. (Never use (entire) namespaces unless you own them.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Can't use c++20.  Compiling this for Android 9+

wohlstad Aye, I put that in for simplicity for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add more braces because the structure is:

```
tweak_cat
{
   string,
   list
   {
       the_tweak { name, value, type },
       the_tweak { name, value, type },
       the_tweak { name, value, type },
   }
}
```

Code:

```
list<tweak_cat> _ret = {
    {
        "debugging",
        {
            {"testing", "0", ""}
        }
    },
    {
        "dozing",
        {
            {"testing2", "this", ""},
            {"testing3", "that", ""},
            {"testing4", "0", "theother"}
        }
    },
};
```

The above should compile.

Comment: Thank you for the extra brain cells.  That certainly did it. :)